# Google Maps v3 get mousewheel event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I setup my own google map with custom colors and markers which will all work fine. But now i want add a mousewheel event but my simple test function "wheelEvent" is not working...

```
-> http://jsfiddle.net/PMk7E/2/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first : There are some errors that prevent the further code from being executed(e.g. undefined `marker1` )

Then: you must add the listener to the map-container:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener($map.getDiv(),'DOMMouseScroll',wheelEvent,true);
```

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/HmyPM/